# How to show the progress of code in R?

Tags: r, progress-bar

I am now dealing with a large dataset and some functions may take hours to process. I wonder how I can show the progress of the code through a progress bar or number(1,2,3,...,100). Here is an example. Thanks.

```
require(Kendall)
mydata=matrix(rnorm(6000*300),ncol = 300)
result=as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 6000,ncol = 2))
for (i in 1:6000) {
  abc=MannKendall(mydata[i,])
  result[i,1]=abc$tau
  result[i,2]=abc$sl
}
```

By the way, I find the link https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/r-monitor-function-progress-with-a-progress-bar/ very usefull. However, I do not know how to combine the code in the link with my own function. Anyone has an idea? Thanks. Here is the code from the above link.

```
total <- 20
# create progress bar
pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = total, style = 3)
for(i in 1:total){
   Sys.sleep(0.1)
   # update progress bar
   setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
}
close(pb)
```

Comment: From the link, you could use `pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = 6000, style = 3); for(i in seq_len(6000)) {<calculation stuff here>;  setTxtProgressBar(pb, i); }; close(pb);`

Comment: @lmo Thank you so much, it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
mydata=matrix(rnorm(6000*300),ncol = 300)
result=as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 6000,ncol = 2))
progression<-winProgressBar(title = "Progress bar", min = 0,max = 6000 , width = 300)
for (i in 1:6000) {
  abc=MannKendall(mydata[i,])
  result[i,1]=abc$tau
  result[i,2]=abc$sl
  setWinProgressBar(progression, i, title=paste(round(progress/6000)*100,"% done"))
}
```

Comment: Is there any way by which we can use such a progress bar outside a function that is a for-loop? So for instance, what about a `ggplot()` call or literally any other command? Normally plotting things shouldn't take longer than a split-second, of course, but take for instance a dictionary analysis where you want to apply a dictionary to large amounts of text and that takes, in my case, 2-3 hours.

Comment: So, would there be a way to add a progress bar to `quanteda::tokens_lookup()` or things like that?

Comment: For the `*apply` family functions, which also tend to usually run for a long time; you can adopt the package called: `pbapply`. It's very cool indeed.

Answer (score 4):

You could add an if statement to output every 100 iterations or so

```
for (i in 1:6000) {
  abc=MannKendall(mydata[i,])
  result[i,1]=abc$tau
  result[i,2]=abc$sl
  if(i %% 100 == 0){
    cat(i)
    cat("..")
  }
}
```

which gives you output of

```
100..200..300..400..
```

Comment: or use `cat(i, "..", "\n")`

Comment: You should not develop the habit of using `cat` for messages. Use `message`.

Comment: @lmo I find this link https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/r-monitor-function-progress-with-a-progress-bar/ very usefull. However, I do not know how to combine the code with my own function. Could you help me with this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Roland When I replace the `cat` with `message`, the output is in a column, do you know how to make the output in a row? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it's lots of functions over a long/multiple scripts all running at once, I use print statements. It also helps narrow down where somethings gone wrong if running all your code at once.

```
print("Now running section 1")

*some code*

print("Now running section 2")

*some more code*
```

Within a single function, I'd use MeetMrMet's answer