# Progress bar on while loop in r studio

Tags: r, progress

I would like to see a progress bar while loop is running. I have a data set with 300,000 variables and takes forever. I would like to use a function or package like 'progress' to show how long the loop will take. With the code below is this possible.

```
           i <- 1
           while (i <= nrow(df)) {
           if (is.na.data.frame(df$case_no[i]))
           df$case_no[i] <- df$case_number[i]
            i <- i + 1
            }
```

Comment: You can print the `i` every 1000 iterations. `if(i%1000 ==0){print(i)}` This is the most simple way to see the progress.

Comment: This ?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682227/how-to-show-the-progress-of-code-in-r and there is a good tutorial here : https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/r-monitor-function-progress-with-a-progress-bar/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can do like this

```
x <- rep(x = NA, times = 100)

pb <- txtProgressBar(0, length(x), style = 3)
for(i in 1:length(x)) {
   setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
   x[i] 
   Sys.sleep(time = 1)
 }
close(pb)
```